# How to print all the Images of PictureBoxes in a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, printing, flowlayoutpanel

I'm struggling to print all the images of `PictureBox-es` which are hosted by a  `FlowLayoutPanel` container.

I've have tried this code but I'm getting an exception:

```cs
private void PrintAllImages()
{
    imagesToPrintCount = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    doc.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;
    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
    dialog.Document = doc;

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        doc.Print();
}

private void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(GetNextImage(), e.MarginBounds);
    e.HasMorePages = imagesToPrintCount > 0;
}

private Image GetNextImage()
{
    //this line I get the error
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)flowLayoutPanel2.Controls[flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Count - imagesToPrintCount];

    imagesToPrintCount--;
    return pictureBox.Image;

}
```

The Exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index -2 is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the task by using the [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.8) class.

- Create a new `Queue<Image>`.
- Get the `PictureBox-es` from the `FlowLayoutPanel` and [Enqueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.enqueue?view=netframework-4.8) their images.
- In the `PrintPage` event, [Dequeue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.dequeue?view=netframework-4.8) the next image and draw it until the queue is empty.

I'll *shrink* your code to the `PrintAllImages()` method as follows:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
//...

private void PrintAllImages()
{
    var queue = new Queue<Image>();

    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(p => p.Image != null)
        .ToList().ForEach(p => queue.Enqueue(p.Image));

    if (queue.Count == 0) return;

    using (var doc = new PrintDocument())
    using (var pd = new PrintDialog())
    {
        pd.Document = doc;
        if(pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(queue.Dequeue(), e.MarginBounds);
                    e.HasMorePages = queue.Count > 0;
                };
            pd.Document.Print();
        }
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: This was perfect bro,

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales Anytime buddy. Good luck.